# Magic line responds to JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

It would be great if someone could help me with this. I have got so far and i'm now stuck! I must admit my JQuery skills are not up to scratch!

Anyway, I'm using a magic line and the #navigation li initiates the .slide using JQuery.

When the #navigation li is clicked i would like the magic line to stay underneath the li that has been selected until the user clicks another one.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/danieljoseph/7Yxn2/2/

Thanks for your help with this. If you have time, an explanation would be great as i'm trying to develop my JQuery.

Thanks for your time.

JQuery:

```
// Magic Line
$(function() {

var $el, leftPos, newWidth;
    $mainNav2 = $("#navigation");

$("#navigation").append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");

var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

$magicLine
    .width($(".current_page_item").width())
    .css("left", $(".current_page_item a").position().left)
    .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
    .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

$("#navigation li").find("a").hover(function() {
    $el = $(this);
    leftPos = $el.position().left;
    newWidth = $el.parent().width();
   console.log($el.parent());
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: leftPos,
        width: newWidth
    });
}, function() {
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
        width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
    });    
});

});


// Services Animations
    $('#ecommerce').click(function(){
    $(".slide2, .slide3, .slide4, .slide5").fadeOut(1000);
    $('.slide1').fadeIn(1000);
    $('.slide .left').addClass('slideUp');
});

    $('#responsive').click(function(){
    $(".slide1, .slide3, .slide4, .slide5").fadeOut(1000);
    $('.slide2').fadeIn(1000);
    $('.slide .left').addClass('slideUp');
});

    $('#logodesign').click(function(){
    $(".slide1, .slide2, .slide4, .slide5").fadeOut(1000);
    $('.slide3').fadeIn(1000);
    $('.slide .left').addClass('slideUp');
});

    $('#branding').click(function(){
    $(".slide1, .slide2, .slide3, .slide5").fadeOut(1000);
    $('.slide4').fadeIn(1000);
    $('.slide .left').addClass('slideUp');
});

    $('#literature').click(function(){
    $(".slide1, .slide2, .slide3, .slide4").fadeOut(1000);
    $('.slide5').fadeIn(1000);
    $('.slide .left').addClass('slideUp');
});
```

Comment: You may want to split up the hover into 2 discrete functions, mouseover and mouseout, so it doesn't automatically return the line to the original position when your mouse leaves the li. That would leave the line there until you move it again with another mouseover event on the next li.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your magic line's `origLeft` data attribute. Add this:

```
$("#navigation a").click(function() {
   $magicLine.data("origLeft", $(this).position().left); 
});
```

At the end of your IIFE

You can modify and change this wherever it goes, but the basic logic is that whenever an `a` tag in the `#navigation` is clicked on, you need to get the tag's left position and set it as the new `origLeft` for the magic line.

Comment: You may want to set another variable, like currentLeft to save the position of the line, without wiping out the origLeft, *if* you need origLeft to reset the line's position to the start.

Comment: That's not really necessary. You never need the original `origLeft`, that's just the left position of the first navigation element. The user will click on the first one if they want the magic line to go there. Even "clicking" the button programmatically will still update `origLeft` correctly